# Can parameter tuning cause overfitting in a clustering problem?

Tags: clustering, overfitting, nonparametric, optimization

I have a dataset. Some of the points (roughly 15%) have been labelled to a particular cluster, but not all of them.

I run the clustering algorithm on the data and evaluate it by:

1. Matching each class to the cluster with the highest number of class instances
2. Evaluating the Precision and Recall of the cluster to get a harmonic mean F-score

The algorithm has parameters, such as the minimum similarity for a pair of points to be clustered (via cosine similarity)

Would it be considered overfitting to run the algorithm on a range of values for each parameter and report the best results?

If so, what approach can I take to avoid this?

Should I hold out some data as a test set?

Comment: I do not understand... Are you using clustering for classification?! How do you define overfitting for clustering?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could run into the problem of over-fitting. Any time you are tuning parameters in hopes of matching some known output (and perhaps in other situations as well) you run the risk over over-fitting. I would suggest holding out some data, using something like cross-validation to tune your parameters, and then seeing how it works on the held out data. If the result is good, re-train it on the entire data set with those parameters and use that going forward.

Note that, as @Prerit mentioned, its not clear if over-fitting will occur in this case. Nevertheless, there is no harm in trying to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

In the literature, you will find several cases of parameter tuning for unsupervised algorithms, in which the authors report only the results obtained by the best combination of parameters (e.g., [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6803941/)).

I had never though of it as overfitting, but simply finding the best scenario for the algorithm to work. The most important thing, though, is to make things clear when presenting your results: "I've got this and this result after a fine parameter tuning etc".

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be fine to run the algorithm multiple times to find the best parameters. Clustering does depend on the initial centroid selection, so you might want to randomize the behavior and then take the average of the metrics. That should avoid overfitting.

Comment: I don't think that's true, is it? Wouldn't it make more sense to treat this as a regular supervised learning problem and (1) take out a test set; (2) do k-fold evaluation on the training set to tune parameters; and (3) evaluate it on the test set?

Comment: Clustering is unsupervised. We can't perform hold out methods. It will lead to not using the whole training set.

Comment: Although clustering is generally considered unsupervised, in this case, the OP has a target function he/she is trying to approximate and is tuning some parameters in order to approximate it. Thus, I would say this is supervised learning, especially if he/she intends to use it to classify/predict new data points.

Comment: @roundsquare Okay but clustering in itself is unsupervised. One has to train the whole dataset to find the clusters, and then classify the test (I think we are trying to learn the distances here, between and within clusters)  but it doesn't make sense to me why use clustering when we have better classification algorithms.

Comment: true, clustering may be a strange choice here since each attempt at clustering does not take into account the target function (although I have seen attempts to match the results of unsupervised learning against a target function before). Nevertheless, the turning of the distance function does take the target function into account. As such, I would think over-fitting could be a problem.

Comment: The comments here is literally the debate I'm having in my head. Thanks to both of you for taking the time.

@prerit - Although clustering does seem, like a strange approach, I'm grouping news articles into event-centric clusters. I'm hoping that clusters that aren't labelled will also pick up events!

Comment: @roundsquare - I agree with the process you outlined in your first comment . It's just complicated by the fact the optimal parameter choice is likely to be proportional to the dataset size. This also goes to the issue of not using all points to cluster

Comment: @roundsquare I agree!

Comment: Using unsupervised techniques in this way is not so strange. For example, I've seen people use topic modeling on documents with known topics to see if those topics get picked up by the topic modeling. One interesting result could be insight from the difference in topics (or, in you case, events) between what the algorithm picks up and how they were manually labeled.

Comment: @roundsquare That is similar to what I am approaching.

I wonder how people go about finding optimal parameters without overfitting in that scenario, for example with LDA, you can select the number of topics to find per document.

Comment: @jfive as far as I know, you just treat it like supervised learning so you can use techniques like cross-validation. In my view, this *is* supervised learning.

Comment: @roundsquare - The actual task is definitely "unsupervised learning", I'm using hierarchical clustering. The cluster analysis uses external validation - this is where the labels are made use of.

I would argue that it isn't supervised learning, but perhaps the task of fitting the correct parameters would be.

Elsewhere, I've seen a solution that suggests clustering training points and clustering test points separately, and measuring the co-prediction - very confused!